# video not loading in html5

Tags: html, html5-video, video-player

I'm having a problem with the HTML5 video player, doesn't show the video, in a html file I have:

```
<video>
          <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
          Video tag not supported.
<video>
```

I even tried without the *codec* atributte in chrome I gets nothing, only the black square of the reproductor

the file *video.mp4* is inside the same folder of the html, it doesn't even show a preview, nothing!

Answer (score 1):

It should work with HTML5 `video` tag perfectly. I've put an example for your reference.

```html
<video controls="" autoplay name="media">
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" type="video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"">
</video>
```

Comment: that's works very fine. I noticed that with my video only plays the sound, why is it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly:

```
<video width="300" height="200" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: that's works very fine. I noticed that with my video only plays the sound, why is it? I played the video with VLC and it's fine, but in the webpage only the sound is played

Comment: Which browser are you using to play the video?

Comment: I'm using chrome and IE. I fixed it, I transformed the video to H.264 codification and now it works. For what I readed this is the codification allowed for the html5 player